# How generate ID or Class for div?

Tags: php, loops, dynamically-generated, id-generation

There is PHP code that when User click on ***the_title();*** then ***the_content*** will be emerged.

My problem is that if there are unlimited ***the_title();*** and ***the_content();***, there is problem with generating ID that it must be unique.

How can i generate for ***href="#id"*** and ***id="id"***???

```
<?php
    // Start the loop.
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

    echo '<a href="#id" data-toggle="collapse">';

        the_title();

    echo '</a>
    <div id="id" class="collapse">';

        the_content();

    echo '</div>';

    // End of the loop.
    endwhile;
?>
```

Comment: use a counter, and add it to the id?

Comment: Is there any Counter function in PHP?

Comment: `$counter = 0; $counter++;` it doesn't get harder than this..

Comment: it doesn't work! i created a $counter and equal it to zero and then assign it to my id="" but it doesn't work!

Comment: some thing like this -> id="<?php $counter ?>" or id="$counter"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use like that example:

```
$i = 1; // counter start from 1
while ($i <= 10):
    echo '<a href="id='.$i.'" data-toggle="collapse"> '.$i.'</a>';
    $i++; // increment 1
endwhile;
```

**Example with your code:**

```
$i = 1; // start counter from  1
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

echo '<a href="#'.$i.'" data-toggle="collapse">';

    the_title();

echo '</a>
<div id="'.$i.'" class="collapse">';
$i++; // counter
    the_content();

echo '</div>';

// End of the loop.
endwhile;
```

**What i have changed?**

Just add a counter in `while loop` initialize with 1

Comment: Look <a href="#id"> is referred to <div id="id">. It means these two id are same and cause to collapse the content

Answer (score 0):

make an array which keeps on increment. use its index like this:

```
<?php echo $new=array('1','2','3','4');?>
foreach($new as $key =>variable){
     echo '<a href="#id<?php echo $key+1;?>" data-toggle="collapse">';
    the_title();
    echo '</a>
    <div id="id<?php echo $key+1;?>" class="collapse">';
    the_content();
    echo '</div>';
}
```

i have tried it. it worked for me. hope you get the idea too how it works.
i am increment the id with the help of key value of the foreach loop.

Comment: it's working by itself! but when i include that with "while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();" it gets error! it's Wordpress single.php page.

Comment: why dont you try foreach(). that is much better option for you.